# PHP : Inversion-of-Control with one-to-many relationship between the classes

Tags: php, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, one-to-many

I have been learning about dependency injection and inversion of control and i'm liking the idea of adopting them in my projects to produce a more decoupled codebase entities.

But I have one question about how to use it with one-to-many relationship .. consider the following two classes `Post` and `Comment`

```
class Post {

    private $content = '';
    private $comments;

    public function __construct($content){
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    // .
    // .

    public function getComments(){
        // the method in question <<---
    }
}
```

--

```
class Comment {

    private $post;
    private $content = '';

    public function __construct(Post $post, $content){
        $this->post = $post;
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    // .
    // .
}
```

Where the Post may have many Comments, now I have a `Post` object that should produce it's `Comments` using some kind of data maybe from database, how I usually do that is in the `Post`'s `getComments` method I use the comments data and **instantiate** `Comment` classes in the method and return array of objects.

I don't feel right about that because I know that I shouldn't instantiate classes from another class, that's not what DI or IoC says, Right?

So what should I do here?

one thing I can do is let the `Post` object handle me the `Comments` data and then I instantiate the `Comments` manually using this data, Something like this:

```
$post = Post::getSomeHow;
$comments = [];

foreach ($post->getComments() as $commentContent) {
    $comments[] = new Comment($post, $commentContent);
}
```